# What are the functions used in firefox browser to generate random numbers to be used in the session keys for SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, firefox, openssl, tls1.2, mozilla

How does Firefox browser generate the random numbers used in session keys for SSL/TLS. Does Firefox browser uses operating system entropy and it's own algorithm to generate the random numbers to be used in session keys? What functions in the source code is used to create the random numbers?